# List index out of bounds: 1 Trigger.NoteOnContentDocument: line 9, column 1: []

Tags: apex, trigger, list, indexing

I All i seem to get stuck with my trigger. I'm very new to triggers i get this error on deployment:

> List index out of bounds: 1 Trigger.NoteOnContentDocument: line 9,
>   column 1: []

Could you please explain why this is happening? Below is my code:

```
trigger NoteOnContentDocument on ContentDocument (before delete) {
        for (ContentDocument c : Trigger.old){          
            List<ContentDocumentLink> links = [
                SELECT LinkedEntityId 
                FROM ContentDocumentLink 
                WHERE ContentDocumentId= :c.Id
            ];
            if (links.size()>0 && Approval.isLocked(links.get(1).LinkedEntityId)){
          c.addError('Approval pending. You do not have the permission to edit/delete this note, please contact your administrator.');    
       }    
      }
    }
```

Comment: You should remove the SOQL from for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the line Due to this you are getting this error

```
if (links.size()>0 && Approval.isLocked(links.get(1).LinkedEntityId))
```

You need to change this

```
if (links.size()>0 && Approval.isLocked(links.get(0).LinkedEntityId))
```

or

```
if (links.size()>1 && Approval.isLocked(links.get(1).LinkedEntityId))
```

Because if size is 1 and you are trying to access second element (remember index starts from 0) so you need to modify condition as given above.

Code sample

```
trigger NoteOnContentDocument on ContentDocument (before delete) {
        for (ContentDocumentLink c : [ SELECT LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId IN: Trigger.old]){          
             if(Approval.isLocked(c.LinkedEntityId)){
          c.addError('Approval pending. You do not have the permission to edit/delete this note, please contact your administrator.');    
       }    
      }
    }
```

In this way you can remove query from for loop.

Comment: @Gianni check my updated answer.

Comment: @Gianni check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks i tries it but the error states: Loop variable must be of type ContentDocument Help??

Comment: @Gianni I jus found that second option will not work. So you need query,

Comment: @Gianni please post this as separate question and if this solves your problem then you can accept this answer.

Comment: I get the following error while trying to delete  node: BeforeDelete caused by: System.QueryException: Implementation restriction: ContentDocumentLink requires a filter by a single Id on ContentDocumentId or LinkedEntityId using the equals operator or multiple Id's using the IN operator.: Trigger.NoteOnContentDocument: line 2, column 1".